# Как посмотреть двоичный код символа utf-16 в Python?

Tags: python

А также: как можно найти символ кодировки utf-16 по его двоичному коду?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'\x44654','UTF-16')
'㙄㐵'
>>> codecs.encode('привет','UTF-16')
b'\xff\xfe?\x04@\x048\x042\x045\x04B\x04'
```